# Composite grammar in Boost::Spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit

I have the following grammar which works as expected.

```
struct query_term {
    std::string term;
    bool is_tag;

    query_term(const std::string &a, bool tag = false): term(a), is_tag(tag) { } };

template<typename Iterator> struct query_grammar: grammar<Iterator, std::vector<query_term>(), space_type> {
    query_grammar():
        query_grammar::base_type(query) {

        word %= +alnum;
        tag  =  (omit[word >> ':'] >> word[_val = phoenix::construct<query_term>(_1, true)]);
        non_tag  =  word[_val = phoenix::construct<query_term>(_1, false)];
        query = (
                  (omit[word >> ':'] >> word[push_back(_val, phoenix::construct<query_term>(_1, true))])
                |
                  word[push_back(_val,
                            phoenix::construct<query_term>(_1))
                  ]
                ) % space;
    };

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), space_type> word;
    qi::rule<Iterator, query_term, space_type> tag;
    qi::rule<Iterator, query_term, space_type> non_tag;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<query_term>(), space_type> query; };
```

But when I replace query with

```
query = (
          tag[phoenix::push_back(_val, _1)]
        |
          word[push_back(_val,
                    phoenix::construct<query_term>(_1))
          ]
        ) % space;
```

code doesn't compile. Basically I am trying to split the grammar into components that can be reused within larger grammar. When a word or tag is parsed, create a query_term object with appropriate flag in **tag** and **word** rule. Re-use these attributes in query rule.

In the previous version, tag and word rules are inlined in the query grammar.

I am not sure what I am missing here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

FYI: This is not the final code. I am trying out the rules before using it in production code.

Thanx,
-- baliga

Comment: IMO, the code isn't pretty. Try tidying it up and you might be able to see where the problem is.

Comment: The code itself is pretty, Boost::Spirit has this operator overload-heavy syntax that you must live with.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Thanx for the suggestion. Some hint would help here.

Comment: Would it be acceptable for me to put in a plug for ANTLR? :)

Comment: @AustinHenley trying to get this done with boost as we don't have ANTLR in our environment, neither have any plan to introduce ANTLR in  our environment.

Comment: Well you have run headlong into one of the fundamental problems with Boost Spirit, which is the hilarious compiler diagnostics when you do something slightly wrong.  Try ANTLR--it really is better.

Comment: I strongly suggest you post code that compiles (see [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions/22762#22762)). This took me far too long to just figure out the missing phoenix namespace qualifications.

Answer (score 5):

The real issue is that you define the attribute for the tag/non_tag rules as `query_term` (instead of `query_term()`).

Some minor issues appear to be:

- using `word` instead of `non_tag` (exposes a std::string which doesn't convert to a `query_type`)
- using `% space` with a space skipper doesn't really make sense
- you probably wanted `lexeme` in the `word` rule because otherwise, it will just keep 'eating' chars regardless of whitespace

Other suggestions:

- avoid excess scope of `using namespace` (or avoid it completely). You *will* run into hard-to-spot or hard-to-fix conflicts (e.g. boost::cref vs. std::cref, std::string vs. qi::string etc).
- try to stay low on the Phoenix usage. In this case, I think you'd be far easier off using `qi::attr` with an adapted struct.
- use BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_* macros to get insight in your parser

Here is the entire grammar, the way I'd suggest it:

```
template<typename Iterator> struct query_grammar: qi::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<query_term>(), qi::space_type>
{
    query_grammar() : query_grammar::base_type(query)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        word    = lexeme[ +alnum ];

        tag     = omit[word >> ':'] >> word >> attr(true);

        non_tag = word >> attr(false);

        query   = *(tag | non_tag);
    };

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()            , qi::space_type> word;
    qi::rule<Iterator, query_term()             , qi::space_type> tag, non_tag;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<query_term>(), qi::space_type> query;
};
```

A fully working example with output (trivially onelined using karma):

```
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

struct query_term {
    std::string term;
    bool is_tag;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(query_term, (std::string,term)(bool,is_tag));

template<typename Iterator> struct query_grammar: qi::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<query_term>(), qi::space_type>
{
    query_grammar() : query_grammar::base_type(query)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        word    = lexeme[ +alnum ];

        tag     = omit[word >> ':'] >> word >> attr(true);

        non_tag = word >> attr(false);

        query   = *(tag | non_tag);

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(word);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(tag);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(non_tag);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(query);
    };

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()            , qi::space_type> word;
    qi::rule<Iterator, query_term()             , qi::space_type> tag, non_tag;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<query_term>(), qi::space_type> query;
};


int main()
{
    const std::string input = "apple tag:beer banana grape";
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;

    query_grammar<It> parser;
    std::vector<query_term> data;

    It f(input.begin()), l(input.end());
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, parser, qi::space, data);

    if (ok)
        std::cout << karma::format(karma::delimit [ karma::auto_ ] % karma::eol, data) << '\n';
    if (f!=l)
        std::cerr << "Unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";

    return ok? 0 : 255;
}
```

Output:

```
apple false 
beer true 
banana false 
grape false
```

Comment: you rock! Thanx for pointing out the query_type vs. query_type(). It was totally a typo and should have been avoided.

Comment: @DudeFromManaglore Haha, anytime!